# send filename and file to python api for upload image

Tags: python, flask-restful

followings are my code for server and client where i want to pass filename in server api so that server and save the image as sender filename.

`server.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import werkzeug
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
class UploadImage(Resource):
      def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        #parser.add_argument('FNAME', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('file', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        imageFile = args['file']
        #filename = args['FNAME']
        #print(filename)
        imageFile.save('test.jpg')

api.add_resource(UploadImage, '/uploadimage')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run()  # run our Flask app
    from waitress import serve
    print("Running....")
    serve(app,host="0.0.0.0",port=8080)
    print("Stopped....")
```

`client.py`

```
import requests
import json
dfile = open("test.jpg", "rb")

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/uploadimage"


test_res = requests.post(url, files = {"file": dfile})

print(test_res)
if test_res.ok:
    print(" File uploaded successfully ! ")
   
else:
    print(" Please Upload again ! ")
```

Comment: What's the actual question? Do you want to use the filename of the original file uploaded? Or do you want to accept an additional form field from the client to name the file something (which is what your commented out code would be doing)?

Comment: i want additional form field. commented out code is not working

Comment: Both server and client must be same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commented-out code you had would work with a small tweak, but if you're going by the standard Flask-RESTful documentation, it doesn't mention that you need to set the `location` on the argument.

With `werkzeug-2.1.0`, the flask-restful `reqparse` now has a 'bug' where if `reqparse` attempts to access an argument using the default `location` parameter, it will raise an exception on the server side. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/936) for more information.

So you need to add your `filename` (or `FNAME` or whatever) argument, but with `location="form"` specified like in the following Flask app that will accept an image in the `file` field, and a `filename` field to specify the name to save it as.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import werkzeug

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

upload_parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
upload_parser.add_argument(
    'file',
    required=True,
    type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage,
    location='files'
)

# note that location="form" is specified
upload_parser.add_argument(
    "filename",
    required=True,
    type=str,
    location="form"
)


class UploadImage(Resource):
    def post(self):
        args = upload_parser.parse_args()
        image = args.file
        image.save(args.filename)


api.add_resource(UploadImage, '/uploadimage')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

    # you can add back your waitress.serve stuff here
    # but I didn't want to bother in my test environment
```

And now I can hit it with a request and have it save my image:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/uploadimage \
  -F "filename=my-image.png" \
  -F "file=@/path/to/image.png"
```